# devops - Why aren't my product backlog items showing on the Boards > Work Items?

Tags: azure-devops, devops, workitem

We use agile. I have some product backlog items. They have Owners, Areas, Iterations. If I go to Boards > Backlogs I can see them. If I go to Boards > Work Items they don't appear. How do I get them to show? I'm not sure what additional information I need to post; feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that I had a filter applied to the list "Recently Updated".